# On chain protocol for validator

Tags: pallet

Do you know if it is possible to create a substrate pallet that implements a specific `function/message` that when it is sent within TX other `validators` pick it up and can respond to it?

Something like a `ping protocol` on the chain.

We send TX with `PING VALIDATOR` X and `VALIDATOR` X can respond with PONG.

Thank you for any replies.

Answer (score 1):

Yes is possible to create a pallet with that logic.

I'd suggest you first of all check the workshop: [Create a new pallet](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/collectibles-workshop/03-create-pallet/) from the Substrate docs where you'll learn how to create a custom Substrate pallet from scratch.

And after take a look into this FRAME pallet that has a logic similar as the one you want to implement: [pallet_im_online](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/im-online/README.md).

> Allows validators to gossip a heartbeat transaction with each new
> session to signal that the node is online.